# Cordova not defined in pushwoosh

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

I have followed the push notification tutorial with pushwoosh from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P2O1jmb7fI).

I have added following js function to my index.js file.

```
 function initPushwoosh()
        {
            var pushNotification = cordova.require("pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification");

            //set push notifications handler
            document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                var title = event.notification.title;
                var userData = event.notification.userdata;

                if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                    console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
                }

                alert(title);
            });

            //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER", pw_appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
            pushNotification.onDeviceReady({ projectid: "XXXXXXXXX", pw_appid : "XXXXXXXX" });

            //register for pushes
            pushNotification.registerDevice(
                    function(status) {
                        var pushToken = status;
                        console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
                    },
                    function(status) {
                        console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                    }
            );
        }
```

I have successfully added the plugin. But the application is not working on a device and in browser I get the following message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

How to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In PushWoosh's sample app, they require the "com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification" cordova plugin but in the documentation, they use "pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification".

If you use plugin name="pushwoosh-cordova-plugin" in your config file, then use "pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification"

If you use plugin name="pushwoosh-pgb-plugin" in your config file, then use "com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification"